# SQL Server 2014 Unattended Install

Tags: sql-server

I'm running through the SQL Server 2014 install wizard, stopping before I get to the final step and then trying to use the Configuration.inf file to do "silentInstalls" on multiple servers.  But, in the wizard I set the services (Ex: SQL Agent, ...) to a domain user, which requires a password.  That password information is not included in the Configuration.inf file, so the unattended install obviously fails.

Questions:

1. I have to use a domain user if I am going to be using replication and other resources that require the SQL Server to communicate with each other, right?
2. How do I include the password for the domain service user in the Config.inf file?

Thanks, 
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't know what else you're using, but you don't need to use a domain user for replication. You can use a SQL account if you'd like ([the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173807.aspx) says so).
2. For the password issue, take a look at the list of parameters you can pass setup.exe ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144259.aspx)). You can mix and match parameters and a config.ini. As such, you can set it up such that all you specify via command line switches is the various passwords you'll need (assuming that the service account is the same between all of your installs).